# How to wait for multiple Flux and Mono publishers to complete concurrently

Tags: java, project-reactor

How to chain Flux & Mono Publishers?

I want to chain them both and send response. Basically, execute all asynchronously.

Here, I use zip for Mono & Flux for executing all Mono publishers and Flux publishers.

```
List<Mono<?>> monoPubs = new ArrayList<>();
Mono.zip(monoPubs, mred -> result);

List<Flux<?>> fluxPubs = new ArrayList<>();
Flux.zip(fluxPubs, fres -> result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the result from the individual publishers, then you can use [`Mono.when`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#when-java.lang.Iterable-) to wait for all publishers to complete:

```java
List<Publisher<?>> publishers = new ArrayList<>(monoPubs);
publishers.addAll(fluxPubs);

Mono.when(publishers)
    .thenReturn(result);
```

In case you need the results from the publishers, then you can use [`Flux.merge`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-java.lang.Iterable-):

```java
List<Publisher<?>> publishers = new ArrayList<>(monoPubs);
publishers.addAll(fluxPubs);

Flux.merge(publishers);
```

Comment: What if I hit 2 different services( 1 Mono an 1 Flux ) and get different result. I need result 1 and result 2 to send a final response to the client. How to get result 1 and result 2 and set in the final object.

Comment: You can use for example `collectList` on `Flux` which will create a `Mono<List<?>>` and then you can `zip` it with the other `Mono`.